# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} (x^2+2y)=1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am going to prove this using the definition:

For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that when $0<\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2 }<\delta$ then $|x^2+2y-1|<\epsilon$.
From here we have that $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$.

Now we can say $$|(x-1)(x+1)+2y|<|x-1||x+1|+2|y|$$

Here's where I'm stuck.
What can we say about the relationship between $|x+1|$ and $\delta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|x-1||x+1|+2|y| \leq |x-1|(|x-1|+2)+2|y|<3|x-1|+2|y|$ provided $|x-1| <1$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, we translate to the origin by setting $z:=x-1$. Now

$$z^2+y^2<\delta^2\implies |z|,|y|<\delta$$ and we want to establish

$$|z^2+2z+2y|<\delta^2+4\delta=\delta(4+\delta)<\epsilon,$$

which is achieved by $\delta<\min\left(\dfrac{\epsilon}5,1\right)$.

Comment: It should be $\delta< min (1,\epsilon/5)$

Comment: @HodaBibo: right, though the wrong expression worked as well.